# flash trivia game with "php & http request" VS "socket server"

Tags: flash, sockets, chat

I want to build a question/answer game with rooms and chat. Is it possible to make it with just PHP and HTTP requests? From you're experience, how many visitors will it hold. I know it's better with socket server but I only have a shared host right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible with only PHP+HTTP. You'd have to have a poller running on a `setInterval` to keep asking the server via `XMLHttpRequest` if there are new lines of chat or game moves, though. How many users you can support depends on how quick that update time must be; if users can wait many seconds between polls you won't have a problem, but if they need split-second updates that's a *lot* of polling and your shared server won't be sufficient at all.

For any realtime responsive chat or action games you would need your own ‘socket server’ type of arrangement, using ‘[Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)’-style long-polling techniques, Flash sockets or, in the future, HTML5's much more convenient WebSocket.

(I'd look at virtual dedicated servers anyway; they're cheap these days and sharing a server for PHP scripts puts you at the mercy of other users for performance and security.)